SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line : 13, file : Code.gs)
I am very new to coding, and I keep getting this error when trying to save my script.
Heres the code:
function myFunction() {
  const calID = '*email*'
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID) 
  const startTime = new Date('2024-04-01 00:00 AM');
  const endTime = new Date('2024-04-30 11:59 PM');
  const events = cal.getEvents(startTime,endTime)
  ScriptApp
   .newTrigger('findNewEvents')
   .forUserCalendar(cal)
   .onEventUpdated()
   .create()
  SpreadsheetApp.
  for (x = 0 ; x<events.lenght;x++);{
    let title = event[x].getTitle(),
    console.log(title);
  }  
}

I want to set a trigger when new events are added in a Google Calendar that will add information from those events to a Google Sheet (information like guests email, and other info that were entered by the guest in the event).

It's not clear if the line number in the error corresponds to your code snippet, but there are some obvious mistakes here. Namely, events.lenght is clearly a spelling error. You also have a rogue semi-colon before the loop body which will result in the loop never doing anything, and the getTitle() line ends in a comma instead of semi-colon, which is probably incorrect. Prior to all this, you have the definition of events missing a semi-colon entirely, as well as the ScriptApp statement that ends in create(). You then have SpreadsheetApp. which seems to be an incomplete statement.

Try it this way:
function myFunction() {
  const calID = '*email*'
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID)
  const startTime = new Date(2024, 3, 1, 0, 0);
  const endTime = new Date(2024, 3, 30, 11, 59);
  const events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime)
//ScriptApp.newTrigger('findNewEvents').forUserCalendar(cal).onEventUpdated().create(); //If you have been running this you probably have a lot of triggers.  I'd take a look and delete some if necessary

    for(let x = 0; x < events.length; x++) {
    let title = events[x].getTitle();
    console.log(title);
  }
}

Not sure why your creating a new trigger everytime you run the function.  It seems like a bad idea to me.
